# Git patch Java Imports

Tags: java, git, import

Is any good way to work around patchs with git and Java imports?

I have a **remote computer** (the one I use at work), working with a branch called **bugX**

Now I'm at home, and I want a "copy" of that branch to my **local computer** to keep working.

So what I've done was to do a pull of the working copy in my **local computer**, and then I  made a patch with the diffs of **bugX** branch against **master** in my **remote computer**, and then I tried to apply that patch to my **local computer** on branch **master**

But the patch keeps failing because the imports are all messed up.

[*] I'm not allowed to push the remote branch and then pull it from here.

EDIT:

I tried to make another branch from master (in the remote computer), and tryed to apply the patch to that branch and also failed.

Comment: How does your local master relate to the remote master? If they're out of sync, you might need to do a `git fetch` / `git merge` (or `git pull`, which combines the two). Or start a fresh branch from `remotes/origin/master`, and apply the diff to it. I'm not sure how Java imports are related -- it's all just lines of text.

Comment: They are the same. I think the differences lay on that the IDE messed up the imports, for example, in some places there are a several:

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
...

and in other places
import java.util.*;

Comment: If you have continuous access to your remote machine during this process it would be infinitely easier to just set up remote mirrors for it on your local machine.

Comment: You could `git add` your local changes, `git stash` to move them aside, apply the patch, and then `git stash pop` to recover the local changes (or `git stash drop` to discard).

Comment: (you could also configure your IDE/editor so that it would always sort imports the same way and do that automatically on save)

Comment: @GargantuChet I don't have local changes, both have the same contents (or that is shown. git pull --rebase gives me "branch is up to date")

Comment: @Perception do you say that I can pull from my computer instead of the repository?

Comment: @eis Either way, the harm is already done.

Comment: If you don't have local changes then there's no reason for a conflict. You said there were differences in the import statements -- those differences are changes.

Comment: @GargantuChet I don't know, patch don't work even with the EDIT I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ssh access to your work computer from home, just add your work repo as a remote on your home pc and pull from there. And yes – you can pull from any git repo, “git servers” are not special in any way. Well they are bare which means they don’t have a working copy, but that is only relevant when **pushing** there.

If you don’t have ssh access to your work computer and are not allowed to push the branch to the central repo, I would recommend setting up a repo somewhere else (e.g. private git repo) and pushing there from work. Or you could just hide your branch on the server by pushing it there, but not as a proper branch (not in `refs/heads`, but e.g. `refs/hidden`).

Comment: I'm using my remote computer as my git repository, and then, from there I push to the main repository

Comment: Not sure I understood your question, but: doesn’t matter.